# Wordpress Add To Cart Button Customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to replace the url of the add to cart buttons for my product pages in woocommerce to a button link pointing to a specific url. The tricky part is, I would like to customize each product URL as opposed to having all product links going to the same url. Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you share your code?

Comment: I have not tried any code yet, because I was not getting any hint how to do it. I will try the codes in the above duplicate answer and see if that works